# Golang text/template multiple conditions with !not operator

Tags: go, go-templates

How can I chain multiple conditions using indirect template functions in Go?

I want to check if `.hello` doesn't contain "world" and `.world` doesn't contain "hello", but I cannot because I got `2009/11/10 23:00:00 executing template: template: content:2:5: executing "content" at <not>: wrong number of args for not: want 1 got 2` error message

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
    "strings"
    "text/template"
)

var (
    templateFuncMap = template.FuncMap{
        "contains": strings.Contains,
    }
)

func main() {
    // Define a template.
    const temp = `
{{if not (contains .hello "hello") (contains .world "hello") }}
        passed
{{else}}
        not passed
{{end}}`

    s := map[string]string{
        "hello": "world",
        "world": "hello",
    }

    t := template.Must(template.New("content").Funcs(templateFuncMap).Parse(temp))
    err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, s)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("executing template:", err)
    }

}
```

Go playground link: https://go.dev/play/p/lWZwjbnSewy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`not` expects one argument, so yo have to use parenthesis.

If you do, the condition you want to negate is `contains "hello" or contains "world"`:

```
{{if not (or (contains .hello "hello") (contains .world "hello")) }}
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/bdHaj5WlhMX)):

```
    not passed
```

You can also write this condition as `not contains "hello" and not contains "world"`, which would look like this:

```
{{if and (not (contains .hello "hello")) (not (contains .world "hello")) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach could be to modify your template function to be `notContains` where the `not` operation is performed within the function itself and then you remove `not` from the template string.

Example of that:

```golang
func notContains(str string, sub string) bool {
    return !strings.Contains(str, sub)
}

var (
    templateFuncMap = template.FuncMap{
        "notContains": notContains,
    }
)
```

Usage in the template:

```golang
{{if and (notContains .hello "world") (notContains .world "hello") }}
        passed
{{else}}
        not passed
{{end}}`
```

Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/t5Xg3t4xWgr